# FileStream Constructors in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET, we can achieve this by `FileStream.FileStream(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access);` as below:

```
public class LoginController : MMBaseController
{  
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Home(string returnUrl){ 
        var fileStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/key.crt"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        string text;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Response response = new Response(text, samlTmp);
    }
}

public class MMBaseController : Controller
{
    //Controller for SignIn, SignOut, OnException, Dispose etc..
}
```

I tried below code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Home(string returnUrl, [FromService] IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    var fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(environment.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("/key.crt").PhysicalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    string text;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

But it is showing:

> The type or namespace name 'FromService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> The type or namespace name 'FromServiceAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can we achieve same in .NET Core? I need to pass file path and specify file mode along with the file read/write permission.

I have tried `File.Open()`. But I get this error even after adding the namespace `using System.IO;`

[image]

> The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Just use `File.ReadAllText()`. That will read the file into a string (uses `utf-8`  as standard).

Comment: @PoulBak it would not work if the file is locked

Comment: Is this within a controller or a middleware? Can you show more context about where you want to use this code?

Comment: I have added some more code in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So two things

1. `File` is an method on your `Controller`. You need to use the full name `System.IO.File`
2. In .NET Core you should inject `IWebHostEnvironment` and then call `environment.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("/key.crt").PhysicalPath` to resolve the relative path to your key file.

All in all, your example could look like this instead

```
public IActionResult YourMethod([FromServices]IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    var fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(environment.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("/key.crt").PhysicalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    string text;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    Response response = new Response(text, samlTmp);
......
```

You should also be able to reduce

```
var fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(environment.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("/key.crt").PhysicalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

to

```
var fileStream = environment.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("/key.crt").CreateReadStream();
```

Comment: if I try above code, I'm facing this error `The type or namespace name 'FromService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Sorry, its `[FromServices]` and its in the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode, FileAccess)` instead

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=net-6.0#system-io-file-open(system-string-system-io-filemode-system-io-fileaccess)

```
var fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: I tried this. But showing invalid over there. I have attached error screenshot in the question.

Comment: So use `System.IO.File`, `File` is a method in your context (`this.File`)